# PHP extensions setup

Tags: php, installation

I have a PHP running on a webserver so i do not have access to PHP root folder.

But my application needs

```
php_zip, php_xml and php_gd2 extensions to be enabled.
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Did you check if they are already installed? `php -m`

Comment: If they're not loaded but are available, you can TRY using `dl()` to load them at runtime, but most likely that'd be locked down.

Comment: I would switch servers if I were you.

Comment: I agree this is off topic, but shouldn't it be migrated to serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reopening the question.

I found a way to do it

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Excel-Implementation-in-XAMPP-Localhost/2/

Thanks all :)